# Как программно запускать браузер из приложения и закрывать его, когда пользователь что-либо скачает?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Мне необходимо сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку открывался браузер и пользователь мог скачать файл и когда хотя бы один из файлов будет скачан - браузер должен закрываться и далее запустившее его прилодение должно получать передний план и имя скаченного файла.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно специфицировать объект **Intent** для того, что бы реализовать данный функционал.

Просто запустить браузер не составляет сложности, однако мне нужна Ваша помощь в реализации вышеописанного оповедения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартно делается это так:

1) Интент `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))` далее запуск активити браузера через `startActivityForResult`

2) Вызвавший интент активити по окончании работы браузера получит `onActivityResult`, где вы сможете в зависимости от результата выставить сообщение или что там у вас.

По параметрам и проч. см. в документации. Но есть одна трабла - заставить браузер закрыться после окончания скачивания - это вряд ли...

Есть конечно варианты реализации функционала другим способом:

- Напрямую выкачивать минуя браузер
- Выкачивать через WebView (по сути все тот же браузер, только как часть вашей проги)

Comment: @Barmaley, щас попробовал добавить **WebView** в своё приложение и повесить на него свой обработчик **setDownloadListener**, однако, при скачивании файла он скачивается так же как и обычно и код в моём обработчике не выполняется. Скажите, пожалуйтса, Вы знаете в чем может быть проблема? Возможно необходимо что-то ещё?

Comment: Если честно, не знаю. Почитайте например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797976/downloadlistener-ondownloadstart-never-called или http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496673/webview-download-opens-browser-window-for-a-short-moment-before-returning-to-web